# What to do if [super init] returns nil?

Tags: objective-c

Take the following code as an example

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // code
    }
    return self;
}
```

I do not want nil to propagate up the calling hierarchy. My initial idea is to throw an exception in case self is nil, make a restore point and abort execution.

Better ideas?

Comment: Kind of a side question - but what do you mean by make a restore point?

Comment: @CarlVeazey save any unsaved data to a temporary file

Comment: I'd consider carefully whether saving data will actually help or hurt the user.  If you get a `nil` in this case, it is clearly because your app is already off the rails.  It is likely that the data in memory may already be corrupt.  Unless you can unequivocally validate that data *or* your app offers some means of versioned loading, then you might simply destroy the last valid save.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NSObject's implementation of `[super init]` will never return nil. [The base implementation just returns self](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm).

In general, the only reason that an initializer returns nil is if a nonfatal error occurred.  For example, you might have called `-initWithContentsOfURL:error:` and passed an invalid URL. By convention, methods that may fail in this way have an `error:` parameter, which contains information about the failure. Most initializers do not have the possibility of a recoverable error, so like NSObject, they will never return nil.

Fatal errors typically throw an exception or abort the program. So checking for nil is no help with them. Your best bet to handle fatal errors is [NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler), although you should be aware that saving data is risky in the case of a fatal error, as the unsaved data may be corrupted. Don't overwrite good data in that case.

Why does objective-c code always check for `nil` in initializers, even when super will never return nil? Convention, mostly. Arguably, by always checking for nil, it becomes easier for a superclass to add a failure condition in the future without requiring subclasses to be changed, but really it's just a convention.

Finally, the initalizer is not the right place to check for failure in a superclass initializer. If recoverable errors are a possibility, the caller should check for the error.

Example:

```
NSError *error;
FooClass *myFoo = [[FooClass alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:blah error:&error]
if (myFoo == nil) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Checking for nil whenever you initialize an object is overkill. This only needs to be done when there is an `error:` argument, or the method has a documented recoverable error.

Comment: Nice answer, totally agree.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:-

> For other sorts of errors, including expected runtime errors, return
>   nil, NO, NULL, or some other type-‐suitable form of zero to the
>   caller. Examples of these errors include the inability to read or
>   write a file, a failure to initialize an object, the inability to
>   establish a network connection, or a failure to locate an object in a
>   collection. Use an NSError object if you feel it necessary to return
>   supplemental information about the error to the sender. An NSError
>   object encapsulates information about an error, including an error
>   code (which can be specific to the Mach, POSIX, or OSStatus domains)
>   and a dictionary of program-‐specific information. The negative value
>   that is directly returned (nil, NO, and so on) should be the principal
>   indicator of error; if you do communicate more specific error
>   information, return an NSError object indirectly in a parameter of the
>   method.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, just don't care and let the `nil` propagate.

If `[super init]` is returning `nil` (i.e. a new object could not be instantiated), something is messed up so badly that your application is likely going to crash in a matter of moments anyway.

Checking for `nil` after every instantiation as suggested by Michael is cumbersome and probably totally useless for the reasons above.

If there's a specific class that you are worried about, and you really want to bail out as quick as possible, go ahead as you planned and throw an exception.

About "*making a restore point*" you can try to save whatever possible, but the scenario is so compromised that there's no guarantee of succeeding.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose "`[super init]`" could throw nil if you're trying to reserve a 20 gig block of memory or something (which nobody doing iOS coding would ever do), but in general, a "`nil`" being returned rarely happens in production code.

The nice thing about "`nil`" being returned is that you can send messages to a nil object and your application won't crash.

But you should always do checks for `nil` after instantiating an object, just to make sure you don't get too deep into something your app (or your user) can't recover from.

In [Apple's "Concepts in Objective C" document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html), they suggest *"When you create an object, you should generally check whether the returned value is nil before proceeding:"*.

Comment: iOS devices have limited memory. The application does not crash but could have unwanted behaviour.

Comment: *You should always do checks for `nil` after instantiating an object*.  Sounds crazy. You check and then what? If you cannot instantiate objects, just give up and embrace the crash, since there's really nothing you can do.

Comment: Apple actually says to check for nil after an init, @GabrielePetronella.  I've modified my answer to point out the document.

Comment: They say so, but have you ever seen any Apple example code doing it after every initialization? Of course not, because it's a crazy and mostly a useless and over-paranoid effort. If there's a **specific** object you care about, fine, but doing it **every** single time is just not practical.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella - The practice is totally ubiquitous in Apple sample code. It may or may not be useless, but it's been best practice in cocoa since there was cocoa.

Comment: @isaac Can you provide examples of Apple sample projects where they check every single object initialization against `nil`?

Comment: I just checked the first five Obj-C sample projects on developer.apple.com/samplecode/‎, each class I looked through did it precisely as the documentation recommends. I wouldn't claim they do it absolutely every time, but in years of looking at the stuff I can say with confidence, they almost always do.

Comment: We must be looking at different code bases, since I randomly picked a recent sample project like [UIKit Dynamics Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013414) and it's never made.

Comment: `[super init]` doesn't usually allocate memory for the object. That happens in `alloc`.

Comment: @ChrisDevereux yup, but it returning `nil` may easily be caused by `alloc` returning `nil` in the first place.

Comment: True, but in that case `-init` would never be called, so it won't cause `[super init]` to return nil.

Comment: Unless `[super init]` allocates and returns a new object, I guess.