# super init returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this case where I just Call the init of Class I made this class is subclass of NSObject.

```
- (instancetype)initArray
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
      //Do Some Logic
    }
return self;
}
```

This is my Call from the App Delegate

```
    CategoryLoader *categoryLoader = [[CategoryLoader alloc]initArray];
```

Whats driving me crazy is that:

- Although it returns nil it goes into the if condition
- It doesn't return nil on other computer with other Xcode

Please note that both Xcode's are 6.3

Solutions i tried:

- Cleaned Cache of Xcode
- Deleted the class and created a new one
- Reinstalled Xcode

Here is a Screenshot of whats happening:

[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestions why could it be returning nil from NSObject and what can i do next ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you subclassing NSArray? If so please refer which methods should be overridden: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/.

Comment: Read it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070970/what-to-do-if-super-init-returns-nil

Comment: Yeah I have read this, But it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: You sure its really nil? Sometimes debugger displays it wrong. Try printing it out.

Comment: @JakubVano Yes its not nil !!!!!! the debugger returns nil while printing it out returned object address!! Thank you that helped me a lot. Can you please post it as answer so people would know that the watch is not always accurate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. That was the problem:

The the scheme was on Release Mode. In this case the watch window displays nil in most of the objects. When I printed the value of self on NSLog it printed its value. The only difference between me and the other Xcode was the scheme.

So the solution is to edit the scheme of the project to be debug.

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 1):

`NSObject`’s implementation of `init` should never return `nil`. This is documented in the [NSObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init): although slightly confusing, the key part is

> The init method defined in the `NSObject` class does no initialization; it simply returns self.

If you are observing it retuning `nil`, either something is not setup how you expect (perhaps the class isn’t a direct subclass of `NSObject`), or you are somehow interpreting the results incorrectly, or there is something wrong at another level. The fact that you observe different results on different machines suggests it might be at another level, like Xcode, the operating system, or the hardware. I can’t help much there; try rebooting.

Also, your method ought to be named `init` not `initArray`. This is not a requirement but a very strong convention. You can read about [Object Initialization in Apple’s *Concepts in Objective-C Programming*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html)

Comment: I have named it init, doesn't differ. Rebooted the machine. Installed Other Xcode. However I created a new project and tried the concept and it was working fine. But i can't do that now, its a huge project.